# Tried capturing multiple photos in Android but didn't work

Tags: android, camera

I'm a newbie in Android and I've been trying to make an Android camera application that is supposed to be able to capture 5 images when we click the camera button. But the code I'm working on doesn't seem to work. Is there anyone that can help please? So far, this is the code:

```
public class CameraDemo extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
Camera camera;
Preview preview;
Button buttonClick;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preview = new Preview(this);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

    buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count = 0;
            while(count < 5){
            preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            count++;
            try {
                wait(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
}


ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
    }
};

/** Handles data for raw picture */
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
};

/** Handles data for jpeg picture */
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            // write to local sandbox file system
                //  outStream = CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()), 0); 
            // Or write to sdcard
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));  
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
    }
};

   }
```

And this is the other class named Preview:

```
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "Preview";

SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera camera;

Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);


        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));  
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                    Preview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera = null;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Paint p= new Paint(Color.RED);
        Log.d(TAG,"draw");
        canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, p );
}
}
```

Comment: You say "doesn't seem to work", can you be more specific?

Comment: when I run the app and click the button, it captured once then it closed itself and didn't save the picture

Comment: No exceptions? Did you try to step in the code to see what happens?